# Minting NFT...do I need to specify something to perform proof-of-stake instead of proof of work?

Tags: go-ethereum, alchemy

That's a simple question, do I need to specify something to perform proof-of-stake minting instead of proof-of-work?

The question came to my mind looking at this Legacy field of alchemy (Transaction Type)

[image]

[Here's](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xeba99a904acdf3823d97c72aa66b559e4ebc236633f1fa37f3e555f0247ce8cd) the EtherScan if you need to check (I don't know where to look at it).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to specify something to perform Pos instead of PoW. The transaction type (0x0 Legacy) is an old transaction format that is still valid for new transactions on the Ethereum network.

Legacy Ethereum transactions will still work and be included in blocks, but they will not benefit directly from the new pricing system. This is due to the fact that upgrading from legacy transactions to new transactions results in the legacy transaction's gas_price entirely being consumed either by the `base_fee_per_gas` and the `priority_fee_per_gas`.

See: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1559.md